# переход в finder при закрытии приложения на Mac os

Tags: windows, mac, macbook

Всем привет, только пару дней назад перешёл на мак и есть вопрос.
Если у меня открыт Nimble commander и я открываю фотографию, то после закрытия фотографии на command + q у меня в фокусе finder а не nimble commander который открыт ниже. Та же ситуация со всеми окнами. Если у меня открыт брузер и я поверх открываю какю либо программу (vscode на пример), то после закрытия верхней программы у меня фокус ставится на finder и я могу навигироваться по рабочему столу а не по браузеру, который был предидущей используемой программой. Как это исправить?
Заранее спасибо!

Пробовал искать в настройках нужный пункт, который бы за это отвечал, но такого нет. в гугле даже и намёка на подобную проблему. хотя может я не правильно формировал запрос...